# How to remove the message below?

Tags: forms, oracle

Message => FRM-40831:  Truncation occurred: value too long for field PHONE.

I have table named 'CLIENT'. The table has many fields. One of the field name is 'PHONE'. The field data type and length is VARCHAR2(20 byte). By using the 'CLIENT' table I have created a form using Forms Developer 10g. It works fine. But I have changed the field length and Forms Property Value as VARCHAR2(40 byte) and Forms Property > Maximum Length = 40. Now the Form data save smoothly. But when I am going to retrieve data the message shows => FRM-40831:  Truncation occurred: value too long for field PHONE.

N.B: The message shows when it gates the value over than 20 characters otherwise not.

How to solve the problem?

Please help me.

Comment: I am not clear your answer. Please describe as details. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have changed the database table column length as VARCHAR2(40 CHAR) but still now the message. Thanks to help.

Comment: Yes, I have solved the problem. I had a 'view' using CLIENT table on the CLIENT form and the view had a column PHONE. So I have change the view's column PHONE =>forms property =>Maximum Length=40 and its OK.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are facing the multi-byte character set problem.
Define your column as `VARCHAR2(40 CHAR)`.
Currently the column can contain only 40 bytes, so if - as I assume - you use multi-byte character set in your database, the truncation occurs.